# setAdapter in RecyclerView cannot be applied to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase

i am trying to fetch data from firebase Realtime database and showing the data in recycler view but it shows an error

```
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Collection");
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryItem>().setQuery(databaseReference,CategoryItem.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryItem, CtegoryViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CtegoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CategoryItem model) {
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImageLink()).into(holder.i1, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            holder.t1.setText(model.getName());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CtegoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout,viewGroup,false);
            return new CtegoryViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Post the error from the logcat.

Comment: Please format the question properly. Code section is not readable. And also post the error you are getting. What error you are getting?

Comment: setAdapter
(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)
in RecyclerView cannot be applied
to
(com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter)

Comment: when i hover on this function recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo